# Attempt function in laravel is flagging error

Tags: laravel

After i have imported all necessary classes the attempt function still flags error and it does not if i call it straight without attaching it to guard..What can i do to solve the problem..Thanks

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $data = array(
            'username'  => $request->input('username'),
            'password'  => $request->input('password')
        );

        $rules = array(
            'username'  => ['required', 'max:12'],
            'password'  => ['required', 'max:6']
        );

        $v = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($v->fails()) 
        {
            return redirect()->back()
                            ->withErrors($v)
                            ->withInput($request->except('password'));
        }
        if (Auth::guard('student')->attempt($data)) 
        {
            return view('/profile', compact(Auth::user()));
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->back()
                                ->withInput($request->except('password'))
                                ->with('error', 'Incorrect Username or password');
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error thrown? Is the `student` guard defined in `config/auth.php`?

Comment: yes it is...and it flag it as an error on visual studio that the attempt method is an undefined method

Comment: And what is the error thrown?

Comment: undefined method 'attempt'.. the error is flag on visual studio

Comment: That looks like a vs problem. I don't use that ide so I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `Auth::guard()` method returns a class that implements one of the guard interfaces:

- `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard`
- `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard`

Only the `StatefulGuard` interface garauntees an `attempt` method, so your problem is either:

1. You didn't implement your guard as a `StatefulGuard`
2. Your IDE lacks the ability to infer the actual return type of of `Auth::guard()`, and just warns you that it can't be sure that the guard is a `StatefulGuard`.

In case it's the latter, you might want to look into [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) - it's a tool to help IDE's understand Laravel behaviour